# Solr 5 schema-less replicate schema

Tags: solr, solr5

I'm using Solr 5.3.1 in schema-less mode, so there is a file created `managed-schema` by Solr when I add fields via API.

My config contains

```
<str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
<str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
<str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
<str name="confFiles">managed-schema</str>
```

but the file is not replicated. (Slave still contains standard managed-schema file). Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anwer it on my own: I've found no solution for replication of managed schema, so I switched to static schema with `schema.xml` and all is fine now.